# Replace string character in np.array

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace, type-conversion

I have a numpy array size (8634,3) that contain numerical values with mixed english and german type, eg. 34,12 and 34.15
`X = np.array(df[['column_a','column_b','column_c']])`
`X.shape`
`(8634,3)`
`X.dtype`
`dtype('O')`

I want to replace the "," with "." using this function:

`int_X = X.replace(',','.')`

But I am getting this error:

`AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'replace'`

Can someone help me with the correct function that I need to use? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.replace()` is a string method, so it won't work directly on numpy arrays. You can define a function to do it on an input string, and then vectorize that function to directly apply it to all elements of the array.

Take a look at the following example code snippet. I've converted the array to str type, done the required replacements and then converted them back to floats.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1.2, 3.4, "4,5", "8,3", 6.9])
a = a.astype(str)
replace_func = np.vectorize(lambda x: float(x.replace(',','.')))
a = replace_func(a)
print(a)

# Out: [1.2 3.4 4.5 8.3 6.9]
```

Alternate method using `np.char.replace()`:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1.2, 3.4, "4,5", "8,3", 6.9])
a = a.astype(str)
a = np.char.replace(a, ',', '.')
a = a.astype(float)
print(a)

# Out: [1.2 3.4 4.5 8.3 6.9]
```

Comment: Hi! thanks for your comment. I still got one error: could not convert string to float: '-'   how can I convert also this character to points?

Comment: "-" this character does not convert to float implicitly. How does this character reside in your data? what is your expected output? can you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with

```
int_X = int_X.astype(str)
int_X = np.char.replace(X, ',', '.')
```

Example

```
int_X = np.array([34.12, 34.15, 56.15, "7,1", 80.16])
int_X = int_X .astype(str)
int_X = np.char.replace(int_X, ',', '.')
int_X
array(['34.12', '34.15', '56.15', '7.1', '80.16'], dtype='<U5')
int_X = int_X.astype(float)
int_X
array([34.12, 34.15, 56.15,  7.1 , 80.16])
```